# Pegar parâmetros passados por url em outra página

Tags: c#, asp.net, querystring

Tenho esse chamado a outra página, passando 2 parâmetros.

```
Response.Redirect("/frmPVFichaCadastral.aspx?CdProcesso=" + vhdfCdProcesso.Value + "&CdTipoUsuario=" + vhdfCdTipoUsuario.Value)
```

Como eu pego esses parâmetros passados aqui nessa página `/frmPVFichaCadastral.aspx`?

Comment: vhdfCdProcesso, sério?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utliizando [Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string CdProcesso = Request.QueryString["CdProcesso"];
string CdTipoUsuario = Request["CdTipoUsuario"];
```

A primeira linha demonstra a captura do valor diretamente via coleção QueryString. A segunda, que o valor também pode ser obtido via *indexed property* do object `Request` - contanto que o nome seja único entre a coleção `Form` e a coleção `QueryString`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
string CdProcesso1 = Request.QueryString["CdProcesso"];
string CdProcesso2 = Request["CdProcesso"];
```